# WPF Formatted Text : Calculate font size to fill available height space

Tags: c#, wpf, font-size, formatted-text

This is my `FormattedText` that is child of a canvas :

```
             this.formattedText = new FormattedText(
                                "This is a text to test",
                                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                                this.FlowDirection,
                                new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),
                                this.FontSize,
                                Fill);
```

Please see this image:

[image]

The third form is something that I want,
But I don't know how to calculate the size of fonts to fit height (Not width),
Because there are different fonts with different height,and different `FontFamily.LineSpacing`.

**Note** : I don't want to use `ViewBox`, Because I want to animate the text as crawl text and ticker.

**UPDATE:**

Some fonts need to the `FontSize` more than the height of control, it depends on `FontFamily.LineSpacing`. I can remove the upper space by set the `LineHeight`, but I can't calculate new FontSize based on `FontFamily.LineSpacing`.

Please help me.

Comment: hmm..Have you tried to set your `formattedText` font size to `this.height`? `this.formattedText = new FormattedText(
                                "This is a text to test",
                                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                                this.FlowDirection,
                                new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),
                                this.Height,
                                Fill);`

Comment: yes, I've also set the `FontSize` to parent height. But the problem is that there is  lower space. (some fonts needed a size more than height of control, it depends on `FontFamily.LineSpacing`.

I can remove the upper space by set the `LineHeight`, but I can't calculate new FontSize to remove the lower space.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop to get the maximum font size (stepsize 1):

```
int MaxFontSize = 0;
FormattedText Ft = ... //Your formatted text
while(true)
{
  Ft.SetFontSize(MaxFontSize);
  if (Ft.Height > MaxHeigthOfControl)
  {
    //Too large! Maxmimum size found one step before
    MaxFontSize--;
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    MaxFontSize++;
  }
}
//MaxFontSize is the maximum possible FontSize
```

If this incremantal way is to slow ... try out to do it with an aproximation like shown in this picture:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I've also set the maximum possible `FontSize`, But the problem is that there are upper and lower space.
I can remove the upper space by set the `LineHeight`, but I can't remove the lower space.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you need to understand that FormattedText control is more complex than you think.

There is a `LineHeight`, `BaseLine` and `TextAlignment` property that will affect the areas of layout that you are interested in. Try changing those properties to get what you need

Comment: Thanks for your replay,but I used the `LineHeight` to remove upper space (As I have shown in image) ,the `BaseLine` is read only , and the  `TextAlignment ` property not affect.